# Adobe Flex (mobile): StageWebView and HTML5 features: window.localStorage is null?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, mobile, webview, local-storage

I use FlashDevelop (great and free alternative to Flash Builder) that uses the (latest) open source Flex framework of Adobe.

I want to develop an app for Android and iOS as well. In some parts I use an StageWebView to display content that i don't want to rewrite to flex AS3 code.

In a nutshell: I am in an early stage of development and this is my first flex mobile app. In some parts it uses the HTML5 feature 'localStore' (part of object window in javascript) to store some data. But it seems that this feature is not available in the webkit browser of flex? I also want to know if this is a typical flex problem or does it also exists when the app will be deployed? The problem does not occur when loading the HTML part on a mobile device (for example in mobile safari).

Also when the localStorage feature is not available it will switch back to cookies. But this is also not working correctly. In all other browsers no problemo, even in IE. 
Result of cookie: `varname=undefined; expires=Thu, 03 May 2012 01:01:41 GMT.`

What is going on?

Here is some Javascript code:

```
// Picked up from: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
// Usage: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
        options = jQuery.extend({}, options);

        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
            options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || {};
    var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};
```

Local storage:

```
jQuery.locstore = function(key, val, opt ) {
      var ls = window.localStorage,
          j = window.JSON,  
          b = !( !ls || !j );
      if( !b )
       { return jQuery.cookie( key, val, opt ); }

      // set
     if( arguments.length > 1 )
     { 
       var bRem = (val == null ),
           v = (bRem || typeof val == 'number' || typeof val == 'string')?val:j.stringify(val);
       if( bRem )
        { b = ls.removeItem(key); }
       else { b = ls.setItem(key, v); }
       return b;
     }

     // get
     var v = ls.getItem(key);
     if( v != null && typeof val != 'number' )
      try { v=j.parse(v); } catch(e){}
     return v;
    };
```

I ask it here because i didn't find an answer on the net. Maybe someone give me a clue into the right direction to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it seems that this feature is not available in the webkit browser
>   of flex

There is no webkit browser in the Flex Framework.
A version of Webkit is included in Desktop AIR runtime; but that won't matter for mobile applications.

Mobile AIR uses the underlining browser engine of the OS (Android or iOS) for StageWebView. I'm not sure of specifics; nor what functionality is exposed via the "Browser in the app" but here is a [quote from the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) to confirm this:

> On devices in the mobile and extended mobile profiles, the
>   StageWebView class uses the system web control provided by the device
>   operating system. Thus, the available features and rendering
>   appearance may vary from device to device.

So, I surmise that your issue has nothing to do with Flex, nor AIR, but rather the support of the browser in the OS you're testing on.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Alright, ill get the info. But can you tell me what kind of render engine they use on Android and iPhone because i notice some difference when you put a (webpage that is displayed in safari) onto your homescreen. When you open it with use of the icon placed onto your homescreen, it is not using Safari to display it but with another build-in render engine (AppleWebKit). The next question is: Do it automaticly turn on Javascript (even when it is turned of in Safari) and does it support localStorage when it is a WebView?

Comment: @Erwinus I assume I assume both Android and iPhone use a version of WebKit as their rendering engine.  Different things are supported differently as best I understand.  I don't know what features are supported.  As stated in the doc quote; it depends on the rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

These may be of help to you:
http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/stagewebview-differences-platforms-air-sdk.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html

http://xperiments.es/blog/en/stagewebviewbridge-comunicacion-entre-actionscript-y-javascript-y-viceversa/

http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/07/using-jquery-in-a-flex-application/
(View the previous post also. The link is in the first paragraph.)

Hope one of the last two can help solve the problem / give you a work-around.

Todd

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Air's stageWebView doesn't support **localStorage**. Even though it isn't a perfect solution, after spending months looking for a solution, I replaced localStorage with **sessionStorage**, and was able to load my file correctly.

Take in mind, sessionStorage only works with the loadURL method of stageWebView, loadString doesn't have localStorage nor sessionStorage.

Edit: sessionStorage appears to be working only in android. I can't get neither: localStorage nor sessionStorage to work in Adobe Air for iOs.

Edit 2: Apparently February update of Adobe Air allows localStorage on Android's Adobe Air. (haven't tested it yet)